# Is this an optimal structure for querying MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to find which approach is more scalable. 
I have a user who has requested a seat in a carpool trip, and the user needs to be able to see all trips that apply to them. My models look like this:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   id: String,
   name: String,
   trips: [String]            // An array of strings, which holds the id of trips
});

var TripSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   id: String,
   description: String,
   passengers: [String]       // An array of strings, which holds the id of users
});
```

So when the user goes to see all trips that apply to them, my backend will search through all the trips in the Mongo database. 
I am deciding between 2 approaches:

1. Search through all trips and return the trips where the user's id is in the passengers array
2. Search through all trips and return the trips with an id matching an id in the user's trips array.

I believe approach #2 is better because it does not have to search deeper in the Trip model. I am just seeking confirmation and wondering if there is anything else I should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't do big data, I would simply say that it does not matter - both are good enough, but if you really have millions of queries on millions of users and trips...

- for option 1 you only have one query but you would have to make sure, that you have your field `passengers` indexed, so you would need to maintain another index for this to be efficient. Another index impacts your write performance.
- for option 2 you always have to do two queries.
  First query for the user object in the user collection, then do an `in` style query to load the trip items that match any of those tripIds from `user.trips`. You will query on on the `_id` field which is always indexed. Of course, when you always load your user anyway there is only one query which really counts.

You would also have to consider whether `write` or `read` performance matters more. Your model is pretty inefficient for `write` because for every new trip you need to update two collections (the trip and the user). So currently you double your writes and usually writes are more expensive than reads.

And finally: to have easy and maintainable code is mostly more imporant than a bit of performance --> just use the mongoose `populate` feature, and all is done automatically for you. Don't store the references as Strings but as type ObjectId and use the `ref` keywoard in your model.

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly the insight I was hoping for! I would prefer write performance over negligible read improvements at my scope. I havent used the mongoose populate feature but I will definately look into it. Thanks Reto! :)

Comment: btw. maybe a good read for you - this is from one of most famous computer scientiests ever: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" haha this is going to be a good read